# Google Chrome Extension - Background.html function question

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there anyway by adding to this javascript I can ingore anything after the .com/ .net/ .org/ etc for tab.url.

So if tab.url = examplesite.com/blabla/blabla.html it will replace tab.url with examplesite.com/ and ignore anything after it.

Here's my background.html script.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.create( { url: "http://www.mysite.com/index.php?q=" +tab.url } );
    });
});

</script>
```

Or do I need to program this into mysite to strip the Url? I was wondering if it is possible with Javascript... (not my forte.)

Thank you for any help you may be able to give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not parseUri function built into javascript but you could build what you're asking for using regular expressions. An example of this can be found here:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri

Also, I've never tried to access it from a Chrome extension, but I suspect you have access to the window.location variable which is an object that contains broken down parts of the current page's url. Trying console.log(window.location) and look at the content of the object.